# Tongue and Groove Scraps - Can you create a floor with them

Tags: wood

I'm just finishing installing tongue and groove wood planks on my walls and ceiling. I have quite a few leftover small end pieces, especially at 45 degree angles (pitched ceiling). Can anyone think of a way to use those pieces to create a wood floor (I have 3/4 inch thick white and ponderosa pine). One thing I was thinking about is gluing them to the subfloor and filling the voids with mortar. But I have no idea if this even makes sense.

Comment: I would assume the main difference between a product intended for flooring vs walls is that the flooring would have a more durable finish on it - walls and ceilings wouldn't be required to withstand people and objects moving on them

Comment: In addition to what Steven said, I wouldn't expect mortar to hold up well with wood movement.

Comment: Look into parquetry flooring. I think this is similar to what you want to do. I am skeptical of the mortar part of the plan. But maybe leveling epoxy? It kind of depends on what you come up with for the design, and how much void space is left.

Comment: Yes you can use them for sure, but to make a whole floor you'd need quite a few offcuts :-) If you just want a small part of the floor then how you use them is limited only by your imagination.... or what you can find in Pinterest LOL

Comment: Thanks guys for the comments. I'm trying to.do a non toxic room. So I'm not going to want to add epoxy or polyurethane to the grout. Maybe I can try and come up with some kind of earthen mix. Maybe sawdust mixed with lime , sand. Never worked with these materials before. Yes probably any kind of cement based grout will allow for cracks over time as out handles moisture different than wood. I just wanted to seer if someone has done this type of work or floor before and what their experience was.